# Selecting only first_value by date and ID in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get only first user event (row) for every day.

| date | userId | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | login |
| 2018-09-30 | 2 | login |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | next |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | next |
| 2018-09-30 | 2 | next |
| 2018-09-29 | 1 | login |

and my goal is to get this.

| date | userId | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | login |
| 2018-09-30 | 2 | login |
| 2018-09-29 | 1 | login |

For now I stopped on this. But it returns first date of users activity. But I need only first event of user by date.

```
select *, FIRST_VALUE(date) over(partition by date order by userId) AS firstValue
FROM table
```

| date | userId | event | firstValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | login | 2018-09-29 |
| 2018-09-30 | 2 | login | 2018-09-30 |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | next | 2018-09-29 |
| 2018-09-30 | 1 | next | 2018-09-29 |
| 2018-09-30 | 2 | next | 2018-09-30 |
| 2018-09-29 | 1 | login | 2018-09-29 |

So what should i do to get only first appearence of user by day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your design you are missing some extra column that would define order within the day

If you will use below - this will give you one event per user per day - but no order within the day defined/guaranteed here:

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by userid, date) =  1
```

with output

[image]

meantime if you have some column that can be used to order events within the day - for example - `order_column` - you can use below

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by userid, date order by order_column) =  1
```

Answer (score 0):

First generate a row_number. If there is any other column indicating the order within your dataset, e.g. timestamp or order number, please use it instead. In the next step group by the desired field `date` and `userid`.

To determine the first element `array_agg` the complete column and take the first entry by `offset(0)`. This approach is quite flexible; here also the amounts of events per user and date are shown.

```
select date,userID , array_agg(event order by row_id limit 1)[offset(0)]
,count(1) as event_per_user_date
from(
select *, row_number() over() as row_id
from(
Select "2018-09-30" as date,    1 as userID,    "login" as event
union all select "2018-09-30",  2,  "login"
union all select "2018-09-30",  1   ,"next"
union all select "2018-09-30",  1   ,"next"
union all select "2018-09-30",  2   ,"next"
union all select "2018-09-29",  1   ,"login"
)
)
group by 1,2
```